# Custom User inheriting AbstractBaseUser class not registered when using it in AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm struggling for more than an hour now to get my custom User class working as the default one in Django CMS 1.8.8.

I created a new app called `authentication`, added my custom user model `Account` and custom manager into the models.py file.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        account = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save(using=self._db)
        return account

    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.',
        error_messages={
            'unique': "A user with that username already exists.",
        },
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=True)  # if login with twitter, no email address is passed
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.',
    )

    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
        help_text=(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )

    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Returns the short name for the user."""
        return self.first_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        """Does the user have a specific permission?"""
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        """Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"""
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        """Is the user a member of staff?"""
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

I added the app into `INSTALLED_APP` of mysite settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'treebeard',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_column',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_inherit',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_teaser',
    'djangocms_video',
    'reversion',
    'mysite',
    'authentication'
)
```

At the bottom, I wrote 
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.Account'`

And I got `LookupError: Model 'authentication.Account' not registered.`

But, removing that line, I was able to create a migration, migrate. And when I access the admin, I can add a new `Account` properly.

It's driving me mad. I really don't understand why it's not finding the class in the config, but finding it when it's displaying the admin UI. It makes no sense to me...

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations`?

Comment: `makemigrations` was throwing the model not registered error. Basically, any manage.py command is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Almost everywhere on the internet, people are adding the app to the end of the `INSTALLED_APPS`, but actually, I addded it at the beginning and it's working !

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'authentication',
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'treebeard',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_column',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_inherit',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_teaser',
    'djangocms_video',
    'reversion',
    'rest_framework',
    'mysite',
)
```

EDIT: After some reflection, it's because I mixed-up Django and Django-CMS during my searches. When looking for that issue with Django-CMS, you'll find out your app must be added before the `cms` app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list.
(hum, I can't accept my answer as the correct one, can someone do that ?)

Answer (score 0):

I think as the name of you app is "authentication" conflicts with the authentication inside django.contrib.auth.

Also according to documentation:

> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL has a big effect on your database structure. It changes the tables that are available, and it will affect the construction of foreign keys and many-to-many relationships. If you intend to set AUTH_USER_MODEL, you should set it before creating any migrations or running manage.py migrate for the first time.
>
> Changing this setting after you have tables created is not supported
>   by makemigrations and will result in you having to manually fix your
>   schema, port your data from the old user table, and possibly manually
>   reapply some migrations.

And you should make sure that the model referenced by AUTH_USER_MODEL is created in the first migration of its app (usually called 0001_initial)

Comment: Still same issue, I created a `custom_authentication` app with the same model.
Regarding the migration, I can't even create it because it's throwing the error directly, it's not going further.

Comment: I think you should start from scratch. Drop Database because if it has already been migrated before. Remember that: "Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL has a big effect on your database structure." Thus it should be done first. Make sure that settings are as we agreed on. AUTH_USER_MODEL='custom_authentication.Account'. There is no misspelling in Account model and is subclass from AbstractUser. then try to makemigration to custom_authentication only.

Comment: I found the issue, I answered my question. Thanks for the help :)